# Using php to create customized google map

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, maps

I am trying to create a custom google map using Longitudes and Latitudes that I have in my sql database. So I am trying to place these results directly into my jquery code for the geocoder. But it is not working. Does anyone have ANY idea how I could do this?? I have looked up everything possible and can not find an answer. Thank you so much in advance. Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

var map;
var global_markers = []; 
[<?php 
include 'admin/dbconn.php';

$getLoc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM EanHotels WHERE City = 'Acapulco'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getLoc)){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $lat = $row['Latitud'];
    $lon = $row['Longitude'];
    $address = $row['Address1'];
    echo $lat;
    echo $lon;

?>   
var markers = [[<?php echo $lat ?>, <?php echo $lon ?>, '<?php echo $name ?>'], <?php } ?>
];


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.77627, -73.910965);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    addMarker();
}

function addMarker() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        // obtain the attribues of each marker
        var lat = parseFloat(markers[i][0]);
        var lng = parseFloat(markers[i][1]);
        var trailhead_name = markers[i][2];

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        var contentString = "<html><body><div><p><h2>" + trailhead_name + "</h2></p></div></body></html>";

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Coordinates: " + lat + " , " + lng + " | Trailhead name: " + trailhead_name
        });

        marker['infowindow'] = contentString;

        global_markers[i] = marker;

        google.maps.event.addListener(global_markers[i], 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(this['infowindow']);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}

window.onload = initialize;
//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the output of this script on the `markers` variable? This seems to have something with the formatted number output.

JavaScript expects numbers in the international format, with periods as the decimal separator:  10.2

In some places the server is configured to use comma as the decimal separators, so the output of your script would return an array of numbers, not a number with decimal places:

```
[[ 1,00012, 1,45678, 'name' ]]
```

Also, you have an extra comma at the end of the `markers` variable declaration, before the closing square bracket `]`

Comment: I did not think of seeing the results... I feel like a bit stupid but that was it! I figured it out! Thanks